# How to silence maven noisy upload logs

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I see a lot of upload logs in maven, like:

```
114/970 KB   
116/970 KB   
118/970 KB   
120/970 KB   
122/970 KB   
124/970 KB   
126/970 KB
```

Most of them, seemed to be generated from maven-deploy-plugin while uploading jars to out nexus repository.

Is there way to silence them? Without relying for tools outside of maven, like grep.

With our parallel build system this pollutes our logs badly and it's hard to analyze them without other tools.

I already read:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/
but couldn't find any helpful option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use the `--batch-mode` (or the equivalent `-B`) option to suppress the download output.

```
mvn --batch-mode package
```

Update: May 2023:

```
mvn --no-transfer-progress ..
```

or short version:

```
mvn -ntp ..
```

That also suppresses the Downloaded output etc.

Comment: I use the shorthand for batch-mode: mvn -B package